# Integrate spine animation with React

Tags: reactjs, animation, spine

I was wondering is there a way to use animation exported from spine into a react application?
If there is one, what process should I follow (If there is a documentation or anything that will help)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not specific to React, I mean Spine generates 2D animations that can be used with multiple platforms and languages thanks to spine runtimes.

For example if you want to integrate the animation in your React app you can use the Typescript (it works with Javascript as well) runtime available [here](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/spine-runtimes/tree/3.8/spine-ts)

There're multiple ways to do it, the one I prefer is using the canvas API
, you can find an example [here](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/spine-runtimes/blob/3.8/spine-ts/canvas/example/index.html)

And it is as simple as using the canvas HTML tag wrapped in a React component, with this library [react-canvas](https://github.com/flipboard/react-canvas)

One last point to highlight, if you are trying to use Spine for HTML element animation, it is not the proper tool for this, there're other libraries that are better for this type of use cases, like [react-spring](https://www.react-spring.io/)